# How to uninstall tailwind from my react application?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

I have installed react-bootstrap and tailwind together for my react app. I'm getting some conflict using both of them. So I want to uninstall tailwind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use npm:

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss
```

When you use yarn:

```
yarn remove tailwindcss
```

Answer (score 20):

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss
```

*also (uninstall tailwind dev dependencies, if no other package needs them)*

```
npm uninstall autoprefixer
```

```
npm uninstall postcss
```

For yarn users, use:

```
yarn remove PACKAGE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm remove tailwindcss
```

Also delete the tailwind.config file.

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: remove tailwind.config.js file too